# A certain number when successively divided by $8$ and $11$ leaves remainders of $3$ and $7$, respectively.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A certain number when successively divided by $8$ and $11$ leaves remainders of $3$ and $7$, respectively. What will be the remainder when the number is divided by the product of $8$ and $11$, $88$?

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem?

Answer (score 3):

$n=8a+3=11b+7$. So 8 divides $11b+4$, so $b=4\bmod 8$. Hence $n=11(8k+4)+7=51\bmod88$. Check: $51=6\cdot8+3=4\cdot11+7$.

Comment: Please can you explain this, I've found this theorem....   when a number is divided by two divisor d1 and d2 the two reminders are r1 and r2 are obtained , the reminder that will be obtained by the product of d1 and d2 is given by the relation 'd1r2 + r1'.....therefore d1r2 + r1= 8 * 7 +3 =59